# Generate regex using plain English for AutoHotkey?

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I have read the documentation for at least a hundred times now and still cannot successfully write proper regex to replace strings.

Is there a website that suggests regex using plain english for ahk?

Tried a few websites but didn't work:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPaN8.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT6vn.png

Answer (score 1):

While plain english regex may make it easier (more verbose) to read a regular expression. It's not some AI that you just can feed arbitrary statements and it'll figure it out magically from there (that would be nice though!).

The regex only does the matching and not the actual replacement.

Anyway, if you are just trying to replace some letter or some word, you don't even need regex:

```
; Removes all "e's" from "some sentence"
Result := RegExReplace("some sentence", "e", "")
MsgBox % Result
Exit
```

So try to be a little bit more specific and tell us what you really want to do!

If you want to remove all 4-letter words, you could try

```
Result := RegExReplace("some sentence", "\b\w[a-z]{3}\b", "")
```

hey, the options are endless. I'm just saying that "plain english regex" will not do you much good unless you already know at least *some* regex.

Comment: Based on the specific examples OP provided, I think that he might be able to just not have to worry about the complexities of RegEx entirely, since all they appear to want is a simple "find and remove" script. Ofc, if those were just examples to get their point across, what you just said completely applies. I dream of the day AI will be smart enough to write my RegEx for me lol

Comment: the sample I provided above was just an example. I know how to do simple string replacements, but not complex ones, For instance: take out the string only if preceded by ?utm and do not replace further once you see the & sign. It will be perfect if there's a sample regex database that deals specifically with cleaning up URLs.

Comment: For instance, is this correct?  Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "com.*\K&?utm=.*") ;Remove all UTM tracking links

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples you provided [i.e. "remove `String1` from `String2`]. I wouldn't even bother with RegEx. In most modern languages that can handle strings (including `AutoHotkey`), there are typically `StringReplace` functions.

From the [AHK docs for StrReplace()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StrReplace.htm):

> ### StrReplace() [v1.1.21+]
>
> #### Replaces the specified substring with a newstring.
>
> `ReplacedStr := StrReplace(Haystack, Needle , ReplaceText, OutputVarCount, Limit)`

Here, set the haystack to be your starting string (i.e. `String1`), and your needle to be the text you want to get rid of (i.e. `String2`). Since we don't want to use `ReplaceText`, `OutputVarCount`, or `Limit`, we can just omit them and end the inputs for the function there.

From this, we get

```
outputVar := StrReplace(String1, String2)
```

---

Example:

```
var := "applemangostrawberry"
var1 := ReplacedStr := StrReplace(var, "a")
MsgBox %var1%
```

Output:

```
pplemngostrwberry
```